# Como devuelvo los objectos de un array que cumplan una condicion - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Esotoy aprendiendo MongoDB y estoy intentando resolver algo que aparentemente es sencillo, pero no puedo hacerlo.

Tengo una coleccion en MongoDB con un id, una referencia y un array que contiene objetos, intento devolver con una consulta la coleccion solo  con los objetos que sean "estado" : "en espera".

```
"_id": "600ee69bb44572e071badb",
            "usuario": "600ecfbe178353b50ae4bd7",
            "preguntas": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "id": "39552909"
                    },
                    "_id": "600ee69bb41c0202e071badc",
                    "date_created": "2021-01-25T15:31:47.652Z",
                    "prducto_id": "77777777",
                    "vendedor": "12687820926",
                    "estado": "en espera",
                    "text": "algo de texto",
                    "id": "11727465917"
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "id": "22222222"
                    },
                    "_id": "6333339bb41c0202e071badc",
                    "date_created": "2021-01-25T15:31:47.652Z",
                    "prducto_id": "7777777788",
                    "vendedor": "12687820926",
                    "estado": "completada",
                    "text": "algo de texto",
                    "id": "11727465917"
                }
                ]
```

Esto es lo que intente.

```
let busqueda = await Pregunta.find({ "preguntas.estado": "en espera" });
```

pero me devuelve toda la coleccion completa con los objetos dentro

Les agradezco por su tiempo!

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

La llave `preguntas` del documento, según el esquema, es un array de objects, una solución puede ser [desarmar](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) el array de la llave `preguntas` para luego, regresar un documento que haga [match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) con el valor "en espera" para la llave `estado`.

El `match` se aplica para cada elemento del array en la llave `preguntas`.

Esta operación se puede realizar con [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html), incluye este código en tu función de consulta (tal vez tengas que adaptarlo un poco):

```
const database = client.db("nombre_de_db");

        const agg = [{
                        '$unwind': {
                        'path': '$preguntas', 
                        'includeArrayIndex': 'string', 
                        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$match': {
                        'preguntas.estado': 'en espera'
                        }
                    }];

        const busqueda = await database.collection("nombre_collecion")
        .aggregate(agg,{ allowDiskUse: true })
        .toArray();
        
        console.log(busqueda);
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola, si me funcionó Gracias!!

Comment: Que bien, cuando quieras experimentar con el Framework de agregación, te sugiero intentar mejorar este pipeline con el stage [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), aquí puedes especificar que la consulta regrese solo ciertas llaves, $project fue uno de los primeros stages que aprendi.

Comment: Si consideras que la respuesta fue útil, acéptala como respuesta valida y vota por ella, esto ayudará a que otros usuarios puedan usarla como referencia, al hacer esto puede que ganes tus primeras medallas y puntos, con esto estarás más involucrado en la comunidad, suerte y salud!

Comment: Hola @g.4, una pregunta, porque usas `allowDiskUse`?

Comment: @planta4, lo uso por 2 motivos, el primero es para recordarme que puedo pasar opciones a mi `pipeline`, y segundo porque según la [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html#example-aggregate-method-external-sort), hay límites con respecto a la memoria que se puede utilizar en algún stage durante el proceso de agregación, supongamos un escenario de producción, donde hay muchos datos, con esta opción, mongoDB puede escribir datos en archivos temporales, aunque se excedan los límites de memoria. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Si bien ya te han dado una respuesta bastante completa, te daré otra solución y trataré de explicar el porqué del problema original.

**PROBLEMA**

Dada una colección de documentos de MongoDB, se desea realizar una consulta sobre la misma, usando un modelo de Mongoose. Sin embargo se desea obtener sólo cierta información de los documentos almacenados en la colección. En particular se desea que de la lista de objetos almacenados en el campo `preguntas` sean retornado sólo aquellos cuyo campo `estado` sea igual a la cadena: `"en espera"`.

El problema es que no existe forma mediante una consulta ([`Query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)) a un `Array` de sub-documentos, que se haga un filtrado para traer o mostrar sólo los elementos que deseamos. MongoDB hace una búsqueda en dicho `Array`, si encuentra el sub-documento en la lista, agrega todo el documento al resultado, lo cual incluye **toda** la lista de sub-documentos. Para filtrar y devolver sólo los elementos de la lista que coincidan con el criterio, se debe realizar un proceso de agregación. Tal como propone la [respuesta de @g.4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424285/como-devuelvo-los-objectos-de-un-array-que-cumplan-una-condicion-mongoose/424331#424331).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Otra posible solución es realizar el filtrado después de haber recibido los documentos, es decir, hacer un post proceso de la data consultada para ajustar el resultado obtenido al resultado esperado.

Un proceso de agregación es exactamente lo contrario. El filtrado y procesamiento de la información es realizado por el servidor de base de datos, y si bien esto nos proporciona el resultado *masticado*, dependiendo de la cantidad de información y de lo complejo de la misma, esto puede llegar a ser costoso en recursos. Es por ello que siempre que se pueda, se debe preferir una consulta y post procesado antes que un proceso de agregación.

Actualmente tiene lo siguiente:

```
let busqueda = await Pregunta.find({ "preguntas.estado": "en espera" });
```

Esto como ya hemos visto devuelve documentos que contengan al menos 1 subdocumento en la lista `preguntas` tal que su campo `estado` sea igual a la cadena `"en espera"`.

Una forma directa de filtrar los documentos de esta lista es usar el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de Javascript para los objetos de tipo `Array`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let busqueda = await Pregunta.find({ "preguntas.estado": "en espera" });
busqueda.forEach(resultado => {
  resultado.preguntas = busqueda.preguntas.filter(pregunta => pregunta.estado === "en espera");
});
```

Esto filtrará la lista de preguntas y dejará sólo aquellos elementos que coincidan con el filtro aplicado.

Podemos ver esto en acción en el siguiente código, donde tenemos una lista de documentos que tienen al menos 1 pregunta con estado igual a "en espera":

```js
let documentos = [
  {
    _id: "01",
    preguntas: [
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_1"},
      {estado: "completado", pregunta: "pregunta_2"},
      {estado: "completado", pregunta: "pregunta_3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "02",
    preguntas: [
      {estado: "completado", pregunta: "pregunta_1"},
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_2"},
      {estado: "completado", pregunta: "pregunta_3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "03",
    preguntas: [
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_1"},
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_2"},
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "04",
    preguntas: [
      {estado: "en espera", pregunta: "pregunta_1"}
    ]
  }
];

documentos.forEach(documento => {
  documento.preguntas = documento.preguntas.filter(pregunta => pregunta.estado === "en espera");
});

console.log(documentos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

La salida del código anterior muestra como se ha realizado el proceso de filtrado para quedarnos únicamente con las preguntas que pasen el filtro.

Otra forma de realizar el *post* procesado de la data es crear una función o [método estático](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) sobre el modelo de datos. De esta forma basta con llamar a dicha función para obtener el documento (o documentos), realizando el proceso de filtrado sin que tengamos que preocuparnos por escribir la rutina cada vez que la necesitemos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Nuestro esquema
const PreguntaSchema = new Schema({
  // campos del esquema
});

// El método estático
PreguntaSchema.statics.filtrarPorEstado = async function(filtro) {
  let resultados = await this.find({ 'preguntas.estado': filtro });
  resultados.forEach(resultado => {
    resultado.preguntas = resultado.preguntas.filter(pregunta => pregunta.estado === filtro);
  });
  return resultados;
}

// El modelo
const Pregunta = mongoose.model("Pregunta", PreguntaSchema);

// Ahora podemos usar nuestro método estático:

let busqueda = await Pregunta.filtrarPorEstado("en espera");

// incluso podemos pasar otro valor como filtro:

let otraBusqueda = await Pregunta.filtrarPorEstado("completada");
```

Espero que esto te aclare el porqué del problema y cómo resolverlo de forma alternativa sin usar un proceso de agregación.